# Eclipse - EJB Project - Extracting Jar which contains interfaces

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

During EJB project creation in eclipse, it created following projects

- MyEjbProj
- MyEjbProjClient
- MyEjbProjEAR

The interfaces and implementations are  created in 'MyEjbProj'. The MyEjbProjClient suppose to have interfaces which can be shared to the clients. How to generate/retrieve the jar which can be given to the Clients to use the interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be creating interface in client project only. I have same setup and Eclipse does create interfaces in client project for me. Problem should be either with your facets settings or with module settings. Check following things:

1. Are you selecting EAR and Client project option while creating EJB project.
2. If answer of above question is yes, then check if client and EJB project are shown in deployment assembly settings of EAR.
3. Check if client project have correct facets settings. It must have Java and Utility 2.0 facets.
4. Check if ejb-jar.xml file contains an entry specific to client project. See in following example I have  tag with name of client project:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
   <display-name>TestEJB </display-name>
   <ejb-client-jar>TestEJBClient.jar</ejb-client-jar>
   ```

Comment: Everything is perfect. Now how can I extract the client Jar alone?

Comment: If you have interfaces in client project then just right click the client prject, select Export -> Java -> jar and then follow the wizard. You will get your jar file.